# How to recursively list files with a channel in Go?

Tags: go, recursion, concurrency, channel

I'm trying to use channels to list directory trees recursively.

Currently I get a list of few files and then it gets stuck on one directory. Directory is sent to a worker but it doesn't process it.

How the directory should be sent **inside** the worker (`if file.IsDir()`) so that it gets properly processed and also notify the file lister that there are no new files to be processed after recursion is done?

Here's my current attempt:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "errors"
    "log"
)

// Job for worker
type workerJob struct {
    Root string
}

// Result of a worker
type workerResult struct {
    Filename string
}

func worker(jobs chan workerJob, results chan<- workerResult, done chan bool) {
    for j := range jobs {
        log.Printf(`Directory: %#v`, j.Root)

        dir, err := os.Open(j.Root)

        if err != nil {
            if os.IsPermission(err) {
                // Skip if there's no permission
                continue
            }
            continue
        }

        fInfo, err := dir.Readdir(-1)
        dir.Close()
        if err != nil {
            if os.IsPermission(err) {
                // Skip if there's no permission
                continue
            }
            continue
        }

        for _, file := range fInfo {
            fpath := filepath.Join(dir.Name(), file.Name())

            if file.Mode().IsRegular() {
                // is file
                fs := uint64(file.Size())
                if fs == 0 {
                    // Skip zero sized
                    continue
                }

                r := workerResult{
                    Filename: fpath,
                }

                log.Printf(`sent result: %#v`, r.Filename)
                results <- r
            } else if file.IsDir() {
                // Send directory to be processed by the worker
                nj := workerJob{
                    Root: fpath,
                }
                log.Printf(`sent new dir job: %#v`, nj.Root)
                jobs <- nj
            }
        }

        done <- true
    }
}

func main() {
    dir := `/tmp`

    workerCount := 1

    jobs := make(chan workerJob, workerCount)
    results := make(chan workerResult)
    readDone := make(chan bool)

    // start N workers
    for i := 0; i < workerCount; i++ {
        go worker(jobs, results, readDone)
    }

    jobs <- workerJob{
        Root: dir,
    }

    readloop:
    for {
        select {
        case res := <-results:
            log.Printf(`result=%#v`, res.Filename)
        case _ = <-readDone:
            log.Printf(`got stop`)
            break readloop
        }
    }

}
```

This results in:

```
2018/07/12 14:37:29 Directory: "/tmp"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 sent result: "/tmp/.bashrc"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 result="/tmp/.bashrc"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 sent result: "/tmp/.bash_profile"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 result="/tmp/.bash_profile"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 sent result: "/tmp/.bash_logout"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 result="/tmp/.bash_logout"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 sent result: "/tmp/.xinitrc"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 result="/tmp/.xinitrc"
2018/07/12 14:37:29 sent new dir job: "/tmp/.config"
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [select]:
main.main()
    +0x281

goroutine 5 [chan send]:
main.worker(0xc42005a060, 0xc420078060, 0xc4200780c0)
    +0x4e7
created by main.main
    +0x109

Process finished with exit code 2
```

How the deadlock can be fixed?

Comment: What problems are you having with your current attempt?

Comment: Your main function should not be closing `results`; `close`ing a channel is the responsibility of the write-end.  Additionally, your main function should not have a select with a `default` case: simply continue reading from the `results` channel until it is closed by the last worker.

Comment: @Flimzy `jobs <- nj` hangs forever. the worker doesn't seem to be able to pick it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have noticed that `jobs <- nj` hangs forever. This is because that the operation blocks until a worker receives in the `range` loop, and as long as it blocks there, it cannot reach the `range` loop.

To solve the problem you spawn a new goroutine to do that.

```
go func() {
        jobs <- nj
}()
```

And there is one more problem: your `readDone` channel.

Currently that channel will be emitted every time your `worker` finishes a job, and that leads to the possibility (`select` picks ready channel randomly) that `select` in `func main()` picks it up and then shutdown the system, which makes all remaining job and result lost.

To solve this part of the problem, you should use a `sync.WaitGroup`. Everytime you adds a new job, you call `wg.Add(1)` and everytime your worker finishes a job, you call `wg.Done()`. In `func main()`, you shall spawn a goroutine that use `wg.Wait()` to wait all jobs to finish and then shutdown the system using `readDone`.

```
// One initial job
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    jobs <- workerJob{
        Root: dir,
    }
}()

// When all jobs finished, shutdown the system.
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    readDone <- true
}()
```

Full code: https://play.golang.org/p/KzVxtflu1eU

Comment: This processes far more files than my initial version, but still dies to deadlock after 722363 files. Crash points to `chan receive: for j := range jobs {` and `runtime_Semacquire: wg.Wait()` in `main()`.

Comment: @raspi I forgot to add `wg.Done()` before shipping due to error. Updated full code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial comments on improving the code**

Tim's comment doesn't seem to touch the essentials. It shouldn't matter that you close the channels at the end of `main()`, and neither should it matter that your `select` statement has a `default` case. If there's a message on the channel, the channel-reading case will run.

It could be considered a problem that while there's no message you'll be spinning the loop repeatedly through the `default` case which is going to cause a spike in CPU usage ("busy-waiting"), so yeah, probably just remove the default case.

You might also add a case for a "stop" channel which breaks the `for` loop, using a label (this is needed since otherwise `break` just breaks from the select statement and we loop again):

```
readloop:
for {
    select {
    case res := <-results:
        log.Printf(`result=%#v`, res.Filename)
    case _ = <-stopChan:
        break readloop
}
```

Finally, you should also probably rename the variable `f` in `worker()` to `dir`, since it's a directory and not a file. Just makes the code easier to read. Code should read almost like natural language to a programmer fluent in the language. That way, this statement,

```
fpath := filepath.Join(f.Name(), file.Name())
```

becomes

```
fpath := filepath.Join(dir.Name(), file.Name())
```

... which is a lot easier for your eyes/brain to scan.

**Why is your code broken**

You have a channel deadlock. You didn't notice because of the `default` case meaning that technically, one goroutine can always make "progress". Otherwise the runtime would've thrown panic saying:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

This is because `worker()` has the following structure:

```
receive from channel
...
    ...
    foreach dir in root:
        send to channel
    ...
...
```

But on a normal channel, both send and receive are blocking operations. The goroutine that sends/receives won't make progress until its partner shows up.

You could use a buffered channel to avoid this, but it's impossible to know in advance how many directories will be found in the directory, hence the buffer may be too small. I suggest spawning a goroutine, so that it can block without affecting the overall `worker()` loop:

```
go func() {
    for _, file := range fInfo {
        ...
    }
}()
```

Comment: Ok, added your suggested fixes and crashes now "more properly".

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that the channel send was taking place inside a for loop. Updated with correct answer.